# SED command to replace string after occurrence of a character

Tags: linux, shell, sed, centos

I am trying to run the following command of `sed` :

```
echo "fOO:paSS,tesT2:fail,TESt:pasS,fdfdhfd:pass,test5:anyresult test,test6:pass asfas " | sed  's/:.*/\L&/;s/\w\+/\u&/g;s/:/ # /g;y/,/\n/' | sed 's/\w\+/&\n/2;P;d'
```

The output which I am getting is :

```
FOO # Pass
TesT2 # Fail
Test # Pass
Fdfdhfd # Pass
Test5 # Anyresult
Test6 # Pass
```

Desired Output :

```
fOO # Pass
tesT2 # Fail
TESt # Pass
fdfdhfd # Pass
test5 # anyresult
test6 # Pass
```

What I want is :

1. "**Pass**" & "**fail**" should always have "`P`" & "`F`" capital, no matter whatever input is given.
2. Name of the "**Test**" should remain same as provided in echo command , it should not get changed.
3. After and before of `#` there should be only first word present. If user gives input like "**Test5:Pass successfully**" then **successfully** should not get printed.

Optional requirement:

- Can we convert this to a table anyhow of 2 columns and 'n' rows?

Comment: Then the second line in your desired output is wrong.

Comment: @tripleee corrected it. Thanks.. any idea on answer for this?

Comment: (still) don't understand how you go from `fOO` to `FOO`, from `tesT2` to `TestT2`, from `anyresult` to `Anyresult` ... ???

Comment: the sed command I am using is converting whole words into lower case and then converting every word's first letter as capital. but what I don't want the string mentioned before `:` to get converted to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but think this must be a lot easier with Awk.

```sh
awk BEGIN { RS=','; FS=':' }
NF > 2 { print $1 " # " (tolower($2)s~ /^(test/fail)$/ ? toupper(substr($2, 1, 1)) tolower(substr($2, 2)) : $2) }'
```

Comment: I had to guess or surmise some things because your requirements are not exhaustive. Why should the last output not be printed at all? Why was "anything" capitalized in your desired output? Perhaps still edit your question to clarify these details.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using `sed`, `tr`, and `cut` to match the described spec of what the
   output should be, (rather than the inconsistent desired output in
   the OP):

   ```
   echo "fOO:paSS,tesT2:fail,TESt:pasS,fdfdhfd:pass,test5:anyresult test,test6:pass asfas " | 
      tr ',' '\n' | 
      sed 's/:[fp]/\U&/;s/:/ # /;s/...$/\L&/' | 
      cut -d ' ' -f '1-3'
   ```

   Output:

   ```
     fOO # Pass
     tesT2 # Fail
     TESt # Pass
     fdfdhfd # Pass
     test5 # anyresult
     test6 # Pass
   ```
2. Two column variant output:

   ```
   echo "fOO:paSS,tesT2:fail,TESt:pasS,fdfdhfd:pass,test5:anyresult test,test6:pass asfas " |
      tr ',' '\n' | 
      sed 's/:[fp]/\U&/;s/:/\t/;s/...$/\L&/' | 
      cut -d ' ' -f 1
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   fOO Pass
   tesT2   Fail
   TESt    Pass
   fdfdhfd Pass
   test5   anyresult
   test6   Pass
   ```

Comment: actually @agc the result should be either "Pass" or "Fail" only. 
It should not be anything like "PaSS" or "PasS" or "FaiL".

Comment: I think the best approach would be to take the whole string as it is and convert any occurrence of the pass/fail in any format to either Pass or Fail.

Comment: Hi @agc actually I m able to achieve it with awk command like this : 
`echo  "fOO:paSS,tesT2:fail,TESt:pasS,fdfdhfd:pass,test5:anyresulttest,test6:pass asfas"  | sed -E 's/:/#/g;s/,/ /g;s/(.\S*)(#)(.)(\S*)\s/\1  \2 \U\3\L\4<br>\n/g;' |  awk 'NF < 2 || NF > 3 { $1=""}1' | sed 's/\s//' ` can you tell me how to achieve the column variant for this with a `#` before Pass/Fail ?